# Swift: Cannot get correct height of header cell's label after sizetofit

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uilabel

I have add `sizeToFit()` to UILabel, however I cannot get the correct height which cannot show all text. It just show "**Academic, administrative, teaching and**"

Testing Target: iphone 6

Coding:

```
class eventsViewController: UITableViewController {
     var headerName: Array<String> = ["Academic, administrative, teaching and learning support units"]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.tableView.frame, style: .Grouped)
       self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
       self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 102
    }
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    var headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventsHeaderCell") as! UITableViewCell!

    if headerCell == nil {
        headerCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "EventsHeaderCell")
    }
    headerCell!.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
    headerCell!.textLabel?.text = headerName[section]
    headerCell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    headerCell!.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    headerCell!.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
    headerCell!.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    headerCell!.sizeToFit()
    return headerCell!
   }
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return headerName.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            var headerLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
            headerLabel.text = headerName[section]
            headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            headerLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
            headerLabel.sizeToFit()

            return headerLabel.frame.size.height

        }

}
```

Comment: Try adding it to a view before calling sizeToFit() (you can make it transparent if you don't want your screen to glitch

Comment: Acutally, it show the text, but not  all of it

Comment: The headerLabel variable isn't showing anything in your code, since it's not even displayed on the screen - and I know you just use this variable to calculate the size but still - I'm 99% sure that the sizeToFit method only works for UILabels that are actually in the view hierarchy.

Comment: I have try what you have mention, but it still not working for me and the other texts parts has been hidden. It still return the same width after displayed or it is in the view hierarchy

Comment: Do you expect the label to have multiple lines? You should probably set a frame with the expected width and a large height

Comment: i have tried before i post this question but still not work. `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 102` or make a new frame to with `headerLabel.attributedText?.boundingRectWithSize`

Comment: How should you handle your view? Using Autolayout or AutoResizing?

Comment: I asked you to try setting a frame and not an estimated height or whatever. Just call headerLabel.frame = A RECT WITH 320px width and large height

Comment: I have edit the code content parts for more detail. i have used `headerCell!.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping`,`headerCell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0` `headerCell!.textLabel?.sizeToFit()` for autolayout

Comment: thank you for everyone who try to help

Comment: my purpose is that the admin can edit the data which means that i should not set a fixed size on headerLabel.frame. Also the problem is that it can show the text after i added fixed size on header cell which means that the problem is on headerCell height which caused by the getting "wrong height" of UILabel.

Comment: I will try this again: Your text label that will be shown has a LIMITED WIDTH, therefore the text will have a line break. The problem is that the text label you create in tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:  currently  DOES NOT HAVE a limited width, therefore the height that is returned is just for one row. Therefore, if you would set a frame in the tableView: heightForHeaderInSection: method with the correct width of the label and a large height, you would get the results you want.

Comment: The ios will execute the `viewForHeaderInSection` first, then execute the `heightForHeaderInSection`. Therefore, I create a calculation with the LIMITED WIDTH (Device frame width). Thank you very much for your helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the non-break long text cause getting non-break UILabel height after `sizeToFit()`. But, it shows that the text has been break in iPhone 6 with ios 8.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    var headerLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    var newline: CGFloat = 1
    headerLabel.text = headerName[section]
    headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    headerLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()

    if self.view.frame.width <= headerLabel.frame.width
    {
        newline = ceil(headerLabel.frame.width/self.view.frame.width)
    }

    let tblHeaderHeight = (headerLabel.frame.size.height * newline) + ios7_8Info.getEventHeaderCellSpacingHeight() as CGFloat
    return tblHeaderHeight
}
```